# How to keep the device sensor awake?

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors, foreground-service

Using sensors I am detecting motion for some calculations for which I register sensors on a `Service`.

```
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

For this, I am already using a foreground service with notifications to keep the sensor active.

Below is the code I used on the `Service` class (with higher priority for notification which returns sticky).

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    registerSensor();

 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ServiceNotification.CHANNEL_1_ID)
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            //.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            //.setOngoing(true)
            //.setAutoCancel(true)
            //.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(13, notification);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Android System doesn't kill my app, it runs whole night. But sensor doesn't response until I turn on the screen.

Tried acquiring Wakelock which solves my issue.

```
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MService: WakeLock");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

But I don't want to use `WakeLock` for such long time.

Is there a way by which I can keep the phone's sensors alive for the long run, or am I doing something wrong with my foreground service/notification?
However, I researched a lot on foreground service with higher priorities.

Comment: If you want to receive sensor data, then you need the CPU, right? And that's all the `WakeLock` is doing, is keeping the CPU on. I mean, I could imagine schemes to wake the device a couple times every minute, to save power, but you wouldn't get any data for those times when the device is asleep.

Comment: Would like to see some code example. Could you please post one.
BTW, In my case I wouldn't like to miss any data when the phone moves during its sleeping state (say when screen is off).

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what I was saying. You can either use the `WakeLock` -- which you already said you've got working -- or you can miss some data. There is no third choice.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but still I think there would be some good solution for this, since somewhere it doesn't look feasible to hold cpu for endless time to get sensor data/catch movement.  And what would you suggest if I try to acquire and release wakelocks for some sec on every min. Probably I would need to do this using thread/handler right?
Please shed light on that.

Comment: I do not have time to outline a complete solution, but my general approach would be to use `AlarmManager.setExact()` to wake the device briefly, take a few samples, and then return to sleep. I wouldn't even try to use `JobScheduler`, b/c I don't believe that will let you execute often enough, and thread/handler is also inappropriate, since it is not linked to a power management API, and that's what this is all about: power management. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks   will try it as soon as I get some time to play with this.

Comment: Hi @greeble, can't I use setRepeating or setInexactRepeating and wake up the device on every xx second say (3-4 times/min).
This will increase the number of wakeups but looks better than continuous acquisitions. 
Correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try? You should be able to evaluate how often it is waking up in practice. I think you'll run into some problems if `targetSdkVersion` is >= 19, because what the docs are telling you is that those methods are essentially throttled to a ~15 minute min repeat interval.

Comment: Yes so..I tried with several things and analysed the battery factor spending some days.

When I use setRepeat it doesn't allow me to to repeat alarm with very short gaps like 5 sec on Oreo.
So I used setExact looped it to run on every 5 sec with wakeup of 1sec.

And compared the output of battery stats with continuous wakelock (my prev implementation). Result was quite surprising:

Comment: With continous wakelock for 7.5 hrs whole night, my app juiced 4%, whereas with alarm it ate 7% (with no of wakeups = 4328 & held awake for total 1h12m)
Tried same thing one more time with both case and got very similar result.

Why so... Should I go with my prev solution then? However system warns my app suspicious regarding battery drain where with alarm its not, but too many wakeups oops!!

Hard to take decision with these results. 
Why sensors are like that, still It seems there would be some solutions which is still out of my reach.

Comment: Hmmm, you have a phone that stays running all night, but only uses 4% of its battery? And moreover, you're unsatisfied with that performance? I think I've missed something here. Are you leaving the phone plugged in? And how _exactly_ are you measuring the battery drain?

Comment: It's because I make control of my app running list, I know what should I allow to run and to avoid . I don't use those battery draining app like FB etc and also I prefer to turn off data/WiFi to take a good sleep. But here I am considering my user's case.

And  for testing I started launching that app right after when battery goes to 1% down (say 54 from 55 for eg.) for fair stats. And I personally use gsam app to collect battery statistics with custom time. So the result looks fair and yet surprising for me.

Comment: Your testing procedure actually sounds pretty good, and the results are very counter-intuitive, but the drains are so small I feel you are still within the measurement noise limit. 1.) Your battery could be draining in a non-linear fashion. Start it from 99% for each test. 2.) You don't have perfect control over what other apps are running. 3.) You don't know that the phone is actually going to sleep when you release the wakelock. It may take over 5 seconds to return to sleep. Try a 30 second interval instead.

Comment: 4.) Be satisfied with 4%! That's unbelievably good! What did you expect, that your app would cause the battery to magically self-charge?

Comment: I understand your point, though it's not about my satisfactory. It seems a bad practice to acquire continuous wakelock, letting device awake whole night doesn't sounds good and system also warns this. I wanted to avoid this but the alternative solutions which I tried surprisingly eats more battery (or ok let's say both are same) which forcing me to keep using my existing solution because it's more reliable in terms of my sensor data.

Comment: And you said right I should try to increasing the time to see the difference. however practically I can't apply that since even increasing time to 5 to 7-8 sec, my sensor gets chance to become idle and I face the inconsistency with my data. Yes that's self-explanatory why I am having almost similar battery drain in both the cases since device doesn't sleeps in that small gap.  =>  What do you think should I use continuous wakelock, seems google is not going to like my app ?

Comment: I had assumed when you had the 5 second interval, you were dropping 4 seconds' worth of data, but now I see you were counting on the fact that the phone would not actually sleep in this condition. That also explains the higher battery usage, in my opinion; the phone was never sleeping, & you were causing more code to execute. I thought you understood that the point was to get it to sleep a little bit, but you were just trying to avoid WakeLock use in order to fool Google! Now this makes sense!

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way. Either A.) Your app performs a task that requires the device to stay awake, or B.) it does not. It is the nature of this _task_ that is a bad practice (or not), _not the WakeLock_. The WakeLock is simply a means to an end. Will Google allow it? I have no idea. In my experience, they can be quite capricious. But their decision is probably NOT based on automated WakeLock measurements, b/c I've had apps that use the WakeLock for hours at a time, and they never mentioned it.